# How can i add specific items to my ListBoxItem class?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

The class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Automatic_Record
{
    // <summary>
    /// Class used to represent each item in the listbox.
    /// </summary>
    internal class ListBoxItem : IToolTipDisplayer
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Text that is displayed in the list box.
        /// </summary>
        public string DisplayText { get; private set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Text that is displayed in a tooltip.
        /// </summary>
        public string ToolTipText { get; private set; }

        public ListBoxItem(string displayText, string toolTipText)
        {
            DisplayText = displayText;
            ToolTipText = toolTipText;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns the display text of this item.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>Display text of this item.</returns>
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return DisplayText;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns the tooltip text of this item.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>Tooltip text of this item.</returns>
        public string GetToolTipText()
        {
            return ToolTipText;
        }
    }
}
```

Then in top of form1

```
ListBoxItem[] items = new ListBoxItem[]
            {
                new ListBoxItem("Apple",     "Malus pumila"),
                new ListBoxItem("Banana",    "Porcelia macrocarpa"),
                new ListBoxItem("Kiwi",      "Actinidia deliciosa"),
                new ListBoxItem("Papaya",    "Carica papaya"),
                new ListBoxItem("Mango",     "Mangifera indica"),
                new ListBoxItem("Tomato",    "Lycopersicon esculentum"),
                new ListBoxItem("Lychee",    "Litchi chinensis"),
                new ListBoxItem("Coconut",   "Cocos nucifera"),
                new ListBoxItem("Tangerine", "Citrus reticulata"),
                new ListBoxItem("Avocado",   "Persea americana"),
            };
```

Then in the form1 constructor:

```
toolTipListBox1.Items.AddRange(items);
```

But instead adding this items i want to add this items:

```
toolTipListBox1.Items.AddRange(WindowSnap.GetAllWindows(true, true).ToArray());
```

The problem is i need somehow first to take this array(ToArray) items and make instance for them in the `ListBoxItem[]` items

`toolTipListBox1` is a `UserControl` where i derive it as `ListBox` control.
And I'm doing to use a `tooltip` to display a description over each item in the `listBox`.

In this case i want that the items `WindowSnap.GetAllWindows(true, true).ToArray()` will be also the description i want to see each item since i don't want to make the `listBox` size too big.

GetAllWindows method:

```
public static WindowSnapCollection GetAllWindows(bool minimized, bool specialCapturring)
        {
            windowSnaps = new WindowSnapCollection();
            countMinimizedWindows = minimized;//set minimized flag capture
            useSpecialCapturing = specialCapturring;//set specialcapturing flag
            EnumWindowsCallbackHandler callback = new EnumWindowsCallbackHandler(EnumWindowsCallback);
            EnumWindows(callback, IntPtr.Zero);
            return new WindowSnapCollection(windowSnaps.ToArray(), true);
        }
```

This method is in a class type:

WindowSnapCollection is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace Automatic_Record
{
    class WindowSnapCollection:List<WindowSnap>
    {
        private readonly bool asReadonly = false;

        const string READONLYEXCEPTIONTEXT="The Collection is marked as Read-Only and it cannot be modified";
        private void ThrowAReadonlyException()
        {
            throw new Exception(READONLYEXCEPTIONTEXT);
        }

        public new void Add(WindowSnap item)
        {
            if (this.asReadonly) this.ThrowAReadonlyException();
            base.Add(item);
        }

        public new void AddRange(IEnumerable<WindowSnap> collection)
        {
            if (this.asReadonly) this.ThrowAReadonlyException();
            base.AddRange(collection);
        }

        public new void Clear()
        {
            if (this.asReadonly) this.ThrowAReadonlyException();
            base.Clear();
        }

        public new void Insert(int index,WindowSnap item)
        {
                        if (this.asReadonly) this.ThrowAReadonlyException();
            base.Insert(index,item);
        }

        public new void InsertRange(int index, IEnumerable<WindowSnap> collection)
        {
            if (this.asReadonly) this.ThrowAReadonlyException();
            base.InsertRange(index, collection);
        }

        public new void Remove(WindowSnap item)
        {
            if (this.asReadonly) this.ThrowAReadonlyException();
            base.Remove(item);
        }

        public new void RemoveAll(Predicate<WindowSnap> match)
        {
            if (this.asReadonly) this.ThrowAReadonlyException();
            base.RemoveAll(match);
        }

        public new void RemoveAt(int index)
        {
                        if (this.asReadonly) this.ThrowAReadonlyException();
            base.RemoveAt(index);
        }

        public new void RemoveRange(int index,int count)
        {
                        if (this.asReadonly) this.ThrowAReadonlyException();
            base.RemoveRange(index,count);
        }

        public new void Reverse(int index, int count)
        {
            if (this.asReadonly) this.ThrowAReadonlyException();
            base.Reverse(index, count);
        }

        public new void Reverse()
        {
            if (this.asReadonly) this.ThrowAReadonlyException();
            base.Reverse();
        }

        public new void Sort()
        {
            if (this.asReadonly) this.ThrowAReadonlyException();
            base.Sort();
        }

        public new void Sort(Comparison<WindowSnap> comparison)
        {
            if (this.asReadonly) this.ThrowAReadonlyException();
            base.Sort(comparison);
        }

        public new void Sort(IComparer<WindowSnap> compare)
        {
            if (this.asReadonly) this.ThrowAReadonlyException();
            base.Sort(compare);
        }

        public new void Sort(int index,int count,IComparer<WindowSnap> compare)
        {
            if (this.asReadonly) this.ThrowAReadonlyException();
            base.Sort(index,count,compare);
        }


        public bool Contains(IntPtr hWnd)
        {
            if (GetWindowSnap(hWnd) != null) return true;
            return false;

        }

        public WindowSnap GetWindowSnap(IntPtr hWnd)
        {
            checkHWnd = hWnd;
            return base.Find(IshWndPredict);          
        }

        public void Update(WindowSnap item)
        {
            lock (this)
            {
                WindowSnap oldSnap = this.GetWindowSnap(item.Handle);
                this.Remove(oldSnap);
                this.Add(item);
            }
        }

        public WindowSnapCollection GetAllMinimized()
        {
            WindowSnapCollection wsCol= (WindowSnapCollection) base.FindAll(IsMinimizedPredict);
            return wsCol;
        }

        private static bool IsMinimizedPredict(WindowSnap ws)
        {
            if (ws.IsMinimized) return true;
            return false;
        }

        [ThreadStatic]private static IntPtr checkHWnd;
        private static bool IshWndPredict(WindowSnap ws)
        {
            if (ws.Handle == checkHWnd)
                return true;
            return false;
        }

        public bool ReadOnly
        {
            get{return this.asReadonly;}
        }

        public WindowSnapCollection(WindowSnap[] items, bool asReadOnly)
        {
            base.AddRange(items);
            base.TrimExcess();
            this.asReadonly = asReadOnly;
        }

        public WindowSnapCollection()
        {
            this.asReadonly = false;
        }
    }
}
```

And 
WindowSnap class is:

[WindowSnap class](http://pastebin.com/ymXkbWjH)

This is a screenshot i extended the size of the left listBox just to show how the items have added there. The left window is the line:

```
this.listBoxSnap.Items.AddRange(WindowSnap.GetAllWindows(true, true).ToArray());
```

The right window is the listBox with this line:

```
toolTipListBox1.Items.AddRange(WindowSnap.GetAllWindows(true, true).Select(wnd => new ListBoxItem(wnd.Text, wnd.Text)).ToArray());
```

How can i make the right window using the ListBoxItem to be the items to be like in the left window ? T start from the top without empty lines to show the text near each item Window Text:

And also yo show near each item Handle: ....the number

Just like the left listBox the right one with ListBoxItem.

[image: ListBoxes]

Comment: What does WindowSnap.GetAllWindows return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know `WindowSnap`, but guessing `GetAllWindows` returns `string`s you can do this:

```
toolTipListBox1.Items.AddRange(WindowSnap.GetAllWindows(true, true).Select(s => new ListBoxItem(s, s)).ToArray());
```

**Update:**

Ok, `GetAllWindows` returns a `WindowSnapCollection`, which should implement an `IEnumerable<WindowSnap>`. And `WindowSnap` has a `Text` property which gives you the window title. Do you can use this:

```
toolTipListBox1.Items.AddRange(WindowSnap.GetAllWindows(true, true).Select(wnd => new ListBoxItem(wnd.Text, wnd.Text)).ToArray());
```

**Update 2:**

If I understand your last comment right, you simply want to use the `ToString()` method of the `WindowSnap` class. So just do it:

```
toolTipListBox1.Items.AddRange(WindowSnap.GetAllWindows(true, true).Select(wnd => 
{
    string listBoxItemText = wnd.ToString();
    return new ListBoxItem(listBoxItemText, listBoxItemText);
}).ToArray());
```

The `WindowSnap.ToString()` method gives you the line you want:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
    str.AppendFormat("Window Text: {0}, Handle: {1}", this.text, this.hWnd.ToString());

    return str.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Rene sorry. GetAllWindows not returning string but something else. I updated my question with more information about the WindowSnap and the GetAllWindows.

Comment: Rene can you please look at my question at the bottom i added an update. The code is working but i want to show on the right listBox using the ListBoxItem to be like the left listBox. Sorry.

Comment: @HaimShabort updated again, hope I understood what you meant.